# Does prefix works correctly in Xcode 7 beta 6?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, prefix, xcode7-beta6

I'm trying to add prefix file to my Swift project, that use CoreData. My steps:

1. Create `MySwiftProject-Prefix.pch`;
2. Add header to my `.pch` file (`#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>`);
3. In `Build Settings` of my `Target` set `Precompile Prefix Header` to `Yes` and `Prefix Header` to `MySwiftProject/MySwiftProject-Prefix.pch`;
4. Clean and build project.

And now i get some errors like *you need import CoreData*. But why? Where did i wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a Swift project, it doesn't use a `.pch` file. That's for Objective-C. Simply put `import CoreData` at the top of your Swift file(s).

Comment: Ok. But what if i want to import objective-c lib. Maybe `MagicalRecord`. I should use `.pch` file to import headers.

Comment: No, you can use the bridging header to do that. I repeat: Swift knows nothing of `.pch` files. You're barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: oh yes, sure! My fault. I don't know why i use prefix file instead of bridge header. Well, need to sleep. Thank you very much.